# Как сделать ограничение на ввод в input пробелов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно чтобы при вводе в инпут допускался только один пробел. Предполагаю что для этого надо регулярное выражение.
Только найти не могу... 
Может у кого-то есть другие варианты. )  помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#enter").click(function() {
  var text = $('#input').val();//Получаем значения из инпут
  var count = text.match(/[ ]/g);//Ищим пробелы
  if(count) {//Если есть пробелы
    count = count.length;//Считаем кол-во пробелов
    if(count >=1) {//Проверяем 
      alert('Введено максимальное кол-во пробелов');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
```

Comment: Владимиру нужно чтобы при вводе в инпут допускался только один пробел.               Подправьте условие в коде

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А я вот еще такой вариант сообразил

```js
$(document).on('keydown', '.input-hide', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val().indexOf(' ') !== -1 && e.keyCode === 32) return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='input-hide' placeholder="ограничение пробелов">
```